# Some data format are changed after exporting mysql table to csv

Tags: mysql, excel

I have in mysql table column, type of this column is varchar, in him  saved text data looks like :

```
 4/5
 4/5
 2/3
```

Ok, I want export this table to `csv` format, but after exporting, when I open this csv in excel,  data `4/5` is converted as `04.05.2013`.

I need that after exporting, data like this `4/5` remained as  `4/5` and not changed some another format, how to make this?

Comment: Excel has a habit of auto-formatting some types of values it feels are dates. You can prevent this by opening the CSV using the `Data>>From text` menu: this gives you the option to specify the data type for each imported column.

Answer (score 1):

How the value is displayed depends on regional settings of operating system. (E.g. for windows 7 see Region and Language). In additional seetings there is also spcified CSV separator (List separator), etc..
Those settings are global (for system). They are used e.g. by MS Excel. There is no way how to force Excel to display CSV values the way you want.
You are not supposed to change those system settings. They just give you good reference why your values are displayed in the way they are displayed.

Comment: You could try encapsulating csv values in quotes if you arent't doing it already.